# override func prepare (for segue:) cause in SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, prepared-statement, sigabrt

When I try to transfer the return value of a function from one viewController to another I get the error:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

This is my code in the first viewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let infoPageVC: InfoPageViewController = segue.destination as! InfoPageViewController
        infoPageVC.bestDestination = calculateDestinationForInfo()
```

The function `calculateDestinationForInfo` returns just a Character.

In my second viewController (InfoPageViewController) i used this code:

```
    var bestDestination: Character

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.bestDestination = ""
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
```

I think I am making a mistake in the prepare function but my skills are not yet sufficient to see where it is failing.

Comment: In Interface Builder check the segue identifier (which is **not** the Storyboard ID) and  if the class name of the destination controller is set to `InfoPageViewController `

Comment: Check for segue id (to be sure to not handle unwanted segue) and the check for the type of segue destination before using if

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand what I'm supposed to check, or rather what I'm supposed to do afterwards.

The segue is executed by pressing a button and then leads to a TabBarController.
The ID of the Segue is ```Details```.

The class name of my destination controller is set to ```InfoPageViewController```.

Comment: Never just tell us "signal SIGABRT". When you get a crash, there is an extensive crash log in the Xcode console. You should copy and paste it as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check that segue is correct :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let ident = segue.identifier,
       ident == "Details",
       let infoPageVC = segue.destination as? InfoPageViewController {
        infoPageVC.bestDestination = calculateDestinationForInfo()
    }
    
}
```

This way you are sure of :

- correct segue name
- correct destination view controller type